# How to add padding to bottom of site containing a floated img?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a webpage which has an 'img' floated within a div as the lowest element displayed on page.  The page ends abruptly at the bottom of the image.  For nice aesthetics I would like the user to be able to scroll to just beyond the image (20px or so).  I have attempted to apply margin-bottom and padding-bottom to both the body, a containing div, and the image in question but to no avail.

I have not, and will not try to do this using html to add a buffer or any other hackish solution.

The page: http://www.roughgiraffed.com/about.php
(please don't judge us lol, still very rough (pun intended) and far from deployment)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What you have attempted already should have achieved your desired results with the supplied information. There must be other styles at work that are keeping this from working.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?  Or an example? Or pastebin.org?

Comment: Is this image floating? I've had issues in the past with floating block elements having seemingly ignored margins.

Comment: with out seeing the source, I would hazard a guess at an uncleared float?

Comment: Maybe you could add 20px of transparent space to the bottom of your image.

Comment: Have you used Firebug to look at the layout of your page?

Comment: @ggg transparent space?
@James yes and it showed the styles being applied but still had no effect
@kmfk & leppert I think u may have it

Comment: You should run a spell check on that text. I'm just sayin' ;-)

Comment: @jouke lol maybe u u seen teh orignol un-editd versions?? I editted the post for spelling errors within a minute after pre-emptively posting question.

Comment: Experiance, nefue, still there. I found the solution to the problem, by the way, see my answer.

Comment: @Jouke hahaha!  You got me.  I thought you were referring to my question.  However I refuse to accept blame, instead placing it on Chris who put that text in today.  I assure you I can spell nephew.  (And expeeriants)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` on `#container`. The floats are taking the `.profile` divs out of the flow of the document, which makes the browser think `#container` is only as high as the general text. Setting an overflow somehow resets this. When you've added it, you can set a margin on the container as you normally would.

Comment: Brilliant!  This tip worked like a charm.  Not really sure why it works, but this was just what I needed.

Comment: I don't either. I stumbled into it once after ages of going trough useless samples. I'll never forget it and try to share it as much as possible to save others from that.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following as a test and that makes the body overflow and show a vertical scrollbar. [Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/4tUDr/)

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="imageContainer" style="padding-bottom:1000px;">
         <img src="youImage.jpg"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Also, the following is a slightly different approach:

```
<html style="height: 110%;">
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="imageContainer">
         <img src="youImage.jpg"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>​​​
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but the first approach is similar to what I have been trying (it fails in my case) and the second doesnt really apply to my case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you styled THE element with display:inline?

Inline elements can't have padding or margins

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add margin-bottom to your body tag.

```
body { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Otherwise you can ad that margin-bottom to your container

```
<div id="container"> 
   <img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

#container { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

**NOTE:** both methods worked when tested

Comment: yup thats what I tried to do; problem was related to a floated image as the lowest element on the page I think.  I am updating the original question to reflect this.